# Is discomfort after training okay when rehabbing a muscle fiber tear?

Tags: muscle, pain, fiber

I do bodybuilding and powerlifting and had a muscle fiber tear in my teres major and/or lat (wasn't totally clear on the ultrasound) 4 weeks ago. As directed I gave it full rest for 10 days, then started with some very light movement and exercises around the area that don't work the muscles (i.e. very light cable curls, lateral raises, one arm chest flies, etc).

Now I am slowly starting put train the muscles again using cable rows with 5kg. Doc told me to slowly increase as long as there is no pain. During the workout I didn't feel pain at all. Now, a few hours later I still feel hightened tension in the muscle and something that feels like something between a strong pump and pain when stretching even though the muscles aren't stretched. I would call it discomfort rather than pain and I tend to be relatively pain sensitive.

Is this acceptable or am I doing more damage than good?